# Compare values in a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logic

I have a dictionary has follows:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> 

<A, <2011, 100>>
    <2012, 125>>
    <2013, 142>>
<B, <2011, 350>>
    <2012, 340>>
    <2013, 400>>
<C, <2011, 75>>
    <2012, 80>>
    <2013, 102>>
```

How would I loop through this dictionary to calculate the year or year growth? Where growth is calculated as:

```
Growth = (current year count - (previous year count))/(previous year count)
       = (125 - 100)/100
       = 0.25
```

So the result in a new dictionary would be:

```
<A, <2011, ->>
    <2012, 0.25>>
    <2013, 0.14>>
<B, <2011, ->>
    <2012, -0.03>>
    <2013, 0.18>>
<C, <2011, ->>
    <2012, 0.07>>
    <2013, 0.28>>
```

Now I am not as interested in calculating the growth as I am in learning how to loop through this dictionary to compare values in the same dictionary and then output the results into a new dictionary. There are a whole list of other application where this would come in very useful. My initial thought was to do a for loop within a for loop, but then I cannot figure out how to move back to the previous year because the keys are not the standard 0,1,2,3. I am developing in C# MVC4.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to iterate backwards through a `Dictionary` (or `SortedDictionary`) other than copying the keys to an array and indexing backwards through the array.  (The Linq method [`Enumerable.Reverse`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs.html#e247ee4147678571) actually does this.)

If you need to iterate backwards as well as forwards through the years, rather than a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>`, I suggest using a [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as your inner collection:

```
Dictionary<string, SortedList<string, double>>
```

Or even better

```
Dictionary<string, SortedList<DateTime, double>>
```

The advantage of this is that the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132379%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property implements `Ilist<TKey>`, and thus you can do [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w0148af%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will be log-n.  And if you need to do proximity queries (i.e. find the year closest to a given year) you can roll your own binary search:

```
    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this IList<T> list, T value, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        // Adapted from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = list.Count - 1;
        while (lo <= hi)
        {
            int i = lo + ((hi - lo) >> 1);
            int order = comparer.Compare(list[i], value);

            if (order == 0)
                return i;
            if (order < 0)
            {
                lo = i + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                hi = i - 1;
            }
        }

        return ~lo;
    }
```

The disadvantage of `SortedList` as compared to `Dictionary` is that, if you insert large numbers of items out of order, insertion time is n-squared.  From your description I suspect that will not be a problem for you.

**Update**

Given your `SortedList` of values per year, here are some extensions you might use with it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerate through all items in the list between first and last, inclusive.  First and last need not be in the list.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> Between<TKey, TValue>(this SortedList<TKey, TValue> list, TKey first, TKey last)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var comparer = list.Comparer;
        var index = list.Keys.BinarySearch(first, comparer);
        if (index < 0) // There can be no duplicated keys in SortedList.
            index = ~index;
        for (int count = list.Count; index < count; index++)
        {
            var key = list.Keys[index];
            if (comparer.Compare(key, last) > 0)
                break;
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, list.Values[index]);
        }
    }

    public static SortedList<TKey, double> ComputeGrowth<TKey>(this SortedList<TKey, double> list)
    {
        var count = list.Count;
        SortedList<TKey, double> newList = new SortedList<TKey, double>(count, list.Comparer);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                newList.Add(list.Keys[i], 0.0); // Is this what you want?
            else
                newList.Add(list.Keys[i], (list.Values[i] - list.Values[i - 1]) / list.Values[i - 1]); // Any need to check for division by zero?
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'm quite interested in why you want/need to create this structure in Dictionary. Dictionaries are very specific collections, designed to be used in specific cases, which I'm not sure you needed. So I suggest you consider create a simple list of type like that:

```
new List<MyType>
{
    new MyType { Letter = "A", Year = 2011, Value = 100D },
    new MyType { Letter = "A", Year = 2012, Value = 125D }
};
```

In case you not considered that, you can create a list of anonymous type to calculate like that:

```
var objList = dic
    .SelectMany(s => s.Value.Select(t => new
    {
        Letter = s.Key,
        Year = t.Key,
        Value = t.Value
    }))
    .ToList();
```

And then you can calculate what you want like that:

```
var result = objList
    .Select(current =>
    {
        var last = objList
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Letter == current.Letter
                && f.Year == current.Year - 1);

        return new
        {
            Letter = current.Letter,
            Year = current.Year,
            Calculated = last != null && last.Value != 0
                ? (current.Value - last.Value) / last.Value
                : (double?)null
        };
    })
    .ToList();
```

And if you realy need a dictionary in the end, you can do this:

```
var newDic = result
    .GroupBy(g => g.Letter)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToDictionary(
        k2 => k2.Year, v2 => v2.Calculated));
```

This is NOT the better answer if only think in performance and memory. But this answer came to be good if you want a solution more dynamic and more self explainable.